# Collision of a pictureBox with several pictureBoxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, picturebox

I'm trying to make a Pacman style game for college using only winforms.

I need the player to be able to walk around the maze, staying out of walls.

Currently, my player and the walls are picture boxes, so I need to check for collisions between them.

My current code does it's job well, the problem is that it's extremely slow, and the more items I add to the game (aka more pictureboxes) the slower it gets.

This is my collision code:

```
private string checkCollision(PictureBox collider, int x, int y, int dir, int speed) 
         {                                                                                    
        string pbTag = "NONE";

        foreach (PictureBox collided in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>() )
        {
            pbTag = collided.Tag.ToString();
            if (!(collided == collider) )
            {
                switch (dir) 
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            collider.Location = new Point(x + speed, y); 
                            if (collider.Bounds.IntersectsWith(collided.Bounds)) 
                            {
                                collider.Location = new Point(x, y); 
                                return pbTag;
                            }
                            collider.Location = new Point(x, y);
                            break;
                        }
                   // other directions go here, they are all the same with different x and y values
            }
       }
       return pbTag;
```

As you can see, I use a foreach to cycle through all the picturebox instances, then do the collision checking for each one by moving the picturebox to the new location, checking for collision and then moving it back to where it was (this is so I dont' move the player inside a wall in the movement code).

My question is, what can I do to speed up my collision checking? I managed to get a speed boost by checking for collisions only when the player is aligned with the grid, but it's still very slow and I was going to use the same collision checking for the enemies, which means even more slowdown. I tried limiting the search to only instances near the object looking for collisions by using the collided X and Y values, but since I have some large pictureboxes the range had to be big and the boost was minimal.

Comment: You first must determine which part of the code is causing the problem. Using 10 100 or 1000 pict boxes doesn't tell anything. You just compare integer values. It shouldn't be a problem. Somewhere there is an overhead. Find it.

Comment: Your approach begs overhead.  Instead of running through every object at what must be either preset or random moments, why not code a custom `PictureBox` class that can recognize and report its own collisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using Quad Tree data structure,It is mostly used for collision detection .The optimisation should start right from when you add a picture box to screen.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

There are also ready code snippets in c#,But you need to tailor them to your needs though they wont take much time.

EG: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30535/A-Simple-QuadTree-Implementation-in-C

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, but the truth is that currently I barely know how to use binary trees, and I only had 2 days for this project. Given that during class we were barely taught how to use buttons and labels on winforms, I'm gonna call my functional but slow pacman a win.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern called MVC (Model, View, Control) which says it is better to seperate each component.

based on this pattern, it is better to use a matrix of int (for example) which is a simple definition of each state of the game. 1 means wall, 0 means path, 2 means pacman.

checking the collision in the matrix is much more easier than checking pictureboxes. this is called Model.

you should draw the matrix later on with pictureboxes or whatever. this is called View

and the inputs from keyboard, mouse and databases will effect the matrix only. this is called Control.

with this pattern, using a matrix as a connector to each component, you will definitely reach the highest possible speed.

Comment: I think that would work nicely if everything is always aligned with the grid, but since things are supposed to move at different speeds, I would need a huge matrix (224x228 if going for pacman's original size) and each character would have to occupy several spaces in the matrix. While I'm sure it would probably be faster than using pictureBoxes, I don't think I can handle arrays well enough to make it like that.

Comment: Em, several spaces are not needed. you can check the colision with cartessian distance mesurement. why do you think it is hard to do so?

Comment: Turns out it's a problem somewhere on my computer rather than in the program. Tested the program on my second computer (a much older dual core) and the program runs perfectly, no slowdowns whatsoever. Now I'm clueless as to why it slows in my suppodsedly better quad core computer with 4 times more ram, since both are running win 8.1.